# How to get coordinates from the xml in this form "lat,long"

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, annotations, coordinates

I have successfully got annotations from xml file with this:

```
    double realLatitude = [[[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue];

    double realLongitude = [[[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue];


    MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
    theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;
    myAnnotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(realLatitude,realLongitude);
```

xml file looks like this:

```
<key>Latitude</key>
<string>60.490275</string>
<key>Longitude</key>
<string>22.255962</string>
```

but now I have a large list of points  with coordinates that's look like this:

```
<key>Coordinates</key>
<string>27.864849695000,70.080733147000</string>
```

what I need to change that my code works? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `anns` is the array with the parsed `xml` elements:

```
NSString *coordinates = [[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Coordinates"];
double realLatitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
double realLongitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
```